# Show that $f$ is harmonic

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, riemann-zeta, harmonic-functions, zeta-functions

Let us consider the function:

$$
f(α,β)
\equiv
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n - 1}\left[%
{n^{2\alpha - 1} - 1 \over n^{\alpha}}\,\cos\left(\beta\ln\left(n\right)\right)
\right]
$$

My question is: Show that $f$ is harmonic
$\quad\forall\ s = \alpha + \beta\,{\rm i}\quad$ with $\quad 0 < \alpha < 1$.

Comment: What is $lnn$? Do you mean $\ln n$?

Comment: @5xum: Yes, it is.

Comment: Harmonic in $\alpha$ and $\beta$? In each variable separately or in both simultanously? For $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{D}, \Omega, \dots$?

Comment: @TooOldForMath: Here $α,β∈R$. Yes, Harmonic in $α$ and $β$ or at least for each variable separately.

Comment: So first you may want to check whether the series does at all converge.

Comment: @TooOldForMath: Yes, this is my big concerne.

Comment: Well, if $\alpha>1$, then $(n^{2\alpha-1}-1)/n^\alpha=n^{\alpha-1}-\frac{1}{n^\alpha}>1$ for $n$ large. So the sequence which you are summing does in that case not even converge to $0$, rendering it *impossible* to yield a convergent sum. In cases where it does converge you can use Leibniz' criterion to prove convergece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your analysis seems to be correct.
$$
\begin{align}
f(\alpha,\beta)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{n^{2\alpha-1}-1}{n^\alpha}\right)\cos(\beta\log(n))\\
&=\mathrm{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{n^{2\alpha-1}-1}{n^\alpha}\right)n^{i\beta}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac1nn^{\alpha+i\beta}-\frac1{n^{\alpha-i\beta}}\right)\right)\\[9pt]
&=\mathrm{Re}\left(\eta(1-s)-\eta(\bar{s})\right)
\end{align}
$$
Analytic and conjugate analytic functions are harmonic as is their real part.

---

Since I plotted $f$ for a comment, I include it here. The red line is $\left(\frac12+iy,f\left(\frac12+iy\right)\right)$

$\hspace{4mm}$[image]

Comment: @ robjohn: Can we deduce that if $f(α,β)=0$ then $α=0.5$ as the only solution. I have remarked that if $α=0.5$ then $h$ is identically zero since the strip is open and connected.

Comment: @ robjohn: However, there some values where $f$ is not zero.

Comment: @Zeraoulia.E: I am not sure what you are asking. $f(1/2,\beta)=\eta(1/2-i\beta)-\eta(1/2-i\beta)=0$. I am not sure if that is complete set of zeroes in the strip where the series converges.

Comment: @  robjohn;: I am asking if it is possible to use the **identity theorem** to conclud that $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: @Zeraoulia.E: The [Identity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem#An_improvement) applies to holomorphic functions. $f$ is harmonic and its zeroes can have an accumulation point without vanishing identically.

Comment: So, there is no analogue of this theorem for harmonic functions even in open connected sets.

Comment: @Zeraoulia.E: The [Maximum Modulus Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle#Using_the_maximum_principle_for_harmonic_functions), which does hold for harmonic functions, implies the more restrictive version of the identity theorem (for open sets).

Comment: So $f$ is identically zero in this case.

Comment: @Zeraoulia.E: How do you come to that conclusion? On what open set does $f$ vanish?

Comment: @Zeraoulia.E: [Here is a plot of $f$](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lR3TM.png). It is not a constant.

Comment: @ robjohn: Yes, the function is not idebtically zero. Thank you very much for your good answer.